# Exporting consistent data from Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, export, dump, snapshot

I want to export the content of an Oracle database on a production environment while the application using that database must be running while the export is being performed. Doing a simple "dump" into a file, for example by simply selecting the content of a database and writing it table after table into a file using PL/SQL, does not seem to guarantee consistency. For example, by writing all content of table B into a file, a previously exported table A might have been changed while table B has been exported. The exported contents of B therefore might reference "new" data of table A, wich are not part of the export file of table A. I cannot run this export in one big transaction for performance reasons (the application is running).

Which techniques, tools, etc. can be used to export a consistent set of data into a file from an Oracle database?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Moving targets that don't follow patterns can't be hit unless you get lucky.  The best you could do is pull back everything with date time <= a specific time and clean up discrepancies in the analysis... unless you want to exclusively lock the database while you do your export.

Comment: Why 'export' each table manually when Oracle provide export tools for you? If you really want to do this, are you able to run flashback queries, and is your flashback retention big enough to cover the time needed to query everything you want to dump to files?

Comment: What tools do you have in mind?

Comment: @xSNRG - I was thinking mainly about data pump `expdp`, or `exp` on older versions (pre 10g); some clients have export tools, like SQL Developer, but not sure if they are consistent.

Comment: @Alex Poole: I do not want to export each table manually. This example is for illustration purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flashback enables you to export data consistently.

Every database change records the old data in UNDO.  Oracle uses that data for rollbacks and for read consistency - a SELECT statement can read data from a specific point-in-time.  That same mechanism is used by flashback, but with flashback the point-in-time can be manually set.  If you set the time to the same value for each query then they will all read from the same consistent time.  If there are too many changes and not enough UNDO tablespace you may hit an error like `ORA-01555: snapshot too old`.

If you build your own export process you can use flashback queries like this:

```
select * from test1 as of timestamp timestamp '2015-01-13 20:59:00';
```

If you use export datapump you can use the [flashback_time](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL850) option:

```
FLASHBACK_TIME="TO_TIMESTAMP('25-08-2008 14:35:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')"
```

Answer (score 2):

Which Oracle release are you using?

You can use Oracle data pump, as John Heller said you, including the clause 
FLASHBACK_TIME="TO_TIMESTAMP('25-08-2008 14:35:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')".
if you want to export data consistent at the current time, you can configure the clause in the following way:
FLASHBACK_TIME=systimestamp

If you Oracle release is older then 10.2.0.4, I suggest you to use the exp binary, including the clause "consistent=y".

With data pump you can export data in the past (but it is not always possible). With exp you can export data consistent at the moment when you run the command.

Note that in any case you can take a "Snapshot too old" error. It is because of undo tablespace insufficient space.